# Intel HD graphics 4000 driver only loads in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Don't know when the problem started exactly. Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver has an exclamation point and says "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)"

note: Although in Safe-Mode Windows uses a generic driver, the Intel HD graphic 4000 shows in the device manager without issue.

Hardware:

- Intel i7 3770k
- MB: Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UP4 TH
- NOD32 Internet Security
- Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Facts:

1. I don't have a restore point to before the problem
2. Windows is NOT set to automatically install updates.
3. I did NOT install any new software or 3rd party things.
4. I am only trying x64 drivers

Actions taken thus far (not in any particular order):

1. Researched this issue on MANY forums for 2 days now.
2. Tried MANY versions of the driver that I downloaded from Gigabyte, Intel and Microsoft Update catalog.
3. Tried to update both automatically and manually and by adding legacy device.
4. Tried different settings in BIOS.
5. Tried all the above in safe mode too.
6. Tried to boot while disabling drivers signatures.
7. I am the Admin and have full registry and folder permissions.
8. Intel driver assistant did not find issues.
9. Windows device troubleshooter couldn't not fix the issue.
10. Windows FixIt tool could not fix the issue.
11. 3rd party tools like "UnknownDevices" could not fix the issue.
12. Made sure there were no leftovers by viewing hidden devices.
13. Windows logs shows that it doesn't load.
14. If I uninstall driver and do "scan for hardware changes" it does NOT find it at all. All the above is only if I install legacy device manually and choose "have disk".

If it loads in Safe-Mode, that means that it's ok and that something is blocking it but I can't figure out what.

UPDATE:
Gigabyte contacted me and said I can use the latest driver from Intel's site win64_15.33.46.4885 but as I said, I tried that already. Installing from setup file gives me "This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software" and installing manually (add legacy hardware) leaves an exclamation point and VGA port doesn't work. I also updated all the chipset drivers already.

Comment: In safe mode graphics drivers aren't used. A generic, always compatible, mode is used instead. The main problem here seems to be an inadequate OS - Windows 7 - for the hardware. Intel does NOT support Windows 7 for most of the newer graphics.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, even the newer versions I took from Intel, said WERE for Windows 7 x64, 3rd gen CPU (which is what I have). I also mentioned that I tried with the latest version from Gigabyte and also tried with VERY old versions from 2013 and 2014.

Comment: are you sure it's a 3rd gen cpu? Intell 4000 implies 4th gen (i believe)

Comment: Yes, i7 3770k is a 3rd gen cpu and Intel 4000 HD graphics is for 3rd gens too. It's on the Intel page https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81499/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000

Comment: this is the latest driver for your (and my HD4000): https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27417/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-33-   try to use this driver

Comment: Did you read my question and what I did already? Was it not clear that I tried the latest driver already?

Comment: sorry you mix so many things. in safe mode a generic VGA driver is used not the Intel driver. so it is hard to help you.

Comment: Remarks: (1) Do you see in the Event Viewer any messages relating to the Intel driver? (2) What are the settings in the BIOS that relate to it and is the Intel set to start booting with? (3) Is the installed BIOS version the latest [version F9](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z77X-UP4-TH-rev-10#support-dl) from 2012? If yes, then you might try the beta version F10b but I take no responsibility. (4)  Do you have a second graphics card installed?

Comment: (5) In case of a conflict with in installed product, use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to turn off and on startup products in bunches and then one by one with one click.

Comment: Intel lists a "Device id" for that graphics package as "0x162"; that seems to be *Seventh* generation ( https://ark.intel.com/products/65523/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz )

Comment: @York: 7th gen cpu starts with a 7 (7500, 7560, etc...) https://ark.intel.com/products/series/95544/7th-Generation-Intel-Core-i7-Processors

Comment: @harrymc, I already disabled autoruns in selective mode in msconfig but haven't disabled the Microsoft ones... I'll look into this.

Comment: @harrymc7 1. I have searched this when restarting and no. 2. I've read that ASUS board DO have a Intel graphic setting but on mine, there are no bios settings about Intel Graphics, only 2 other graphic settings that I tried each setting already. 3. My bios version has been F10b for years now. 4. Yes, I have a NVIDIA card. tried with nothing connected to it but didn't disable the card or driver or else I wouldn't see what's going on (thought about using team-viewer from phone though... what do you think)

Comment: I also tried clearing CMOS and dumping static electricity.

Comment: "I DO have an image of my C drive from a few days ago …" – Way to go!

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Try the stable BIOS version F9. (2) See if in Device Manager you can rollback the Intel driver. (3) Have you tried the [Intel Graphics Driver version 15.33](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27417/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-33-?v=t)?

Comment: @ZviTwersky: If you want a solution to your problem and not to waste your bounty, better answer our questions.

Comment: @harrymc :I did not suggest updating the BIOS since the OP clearly said that everything was working fine earlier with the existing version. Since he is using a legacy OS (Win 7), I would not suggest upgrading to the latest drivers/BIOS Updates since they mostly target the newer OSes. We have Win 7 on some of he PCs in my organization and I find that using slightly older drivers on them work best. BIOS update would therefore be a last resort trial in my opinion as this could make matters worse for other hardware.

Comment: @TechLord: One should explore all avenues, and I'm a bit skeptical about discontinued beta software.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that restoring the BIOS by activating Gigabyte's DualBIOS recovery solved the issue.
Q-Flash in BIOS menu forbid downgrading, and may well be the reason why it was overlooked at first.

Comment: Are you the poster? The BIOS being the problem is what I suggested in the comments.

Comment: Even I'd suggested BIOS as the problem in my second answer above, 2 days ago :)

Comment: @harrymc None of you actually provided the mean to downgrade it successfully though.

Comment: @TechLord You have missed the point when you insist the TeamViewer remote diagnosis when the problem is clearly low-level at the BIOS.

Comment: Whatever you like, but if you would have answered the comments we could have recommended for you the DualBIOS utility some time ago.

Comment: @guest: C'mon :) I've been in this field for over 30 years.. I was using **RADMIN**  to  attempt to connect to the OP's system's  BIOS last night (not TV), Was discussing TV in the context of checking out drivers. I think I am done with this thread.. Thank you all :)

Comment: @TechLord I appreciate your many suggestions to help OP. However, at the time of writing there was no definite solution that solved OP's issue. So I provided and posted one before anyone else does. I am in no way undermining your effort to help. Your inquiry from OP actually elucidate the problem and the solution would not have come earlier without you. We might have disagreement regarding some technical details and the share of bounty, but those are complete different issues to the answer posted. I apologize if I have caused any misunderstanding.

Comment: guest has a point. First, I HAD answered EVERY comment. The only thing suggested here about bios was to "check every bios SETTING" which I did. No one besides guest mentioned anything about a dual bios or a backup bios or a corrupt bios (among his many other suggestions). But since it was techlord that actually first got me to conclude (and discuss with others) the bios as being the culprit, and of course in addition, his time and effort, I gave him the points.

Answer (score 2):

I had also seen this problem several times from around October 2017 onwards when several of my clients started to have issues with the Intel Graphics HD 4000 drivers for no apparent reason whatsoever. While many of them had the Windows 10 Creator's Update that could have been the cause of the problem, there were quite a few Windows 7 64-bit PCs that we did not want to upgrade to Windows 10, that developed the same issue.

Of course, when I'd encountered it the very first time, it took quite a while to figure it out since even I'd also tried all the various steps that you'd tried above, with no success.

I will detail **3 solutions** that *actually worked*  on the problematic PCs, without needing a reinstall of the OS.

I am giving 3 solutions rather than a single one, since on every one of the PCs that I needed to resolve the issue on, at least one of the solutions ultimately worked.

**The first solution** would require you to perform all these steps in sequence :

1. In **safe-mode** , uninstall both the chipset drivers as well as the display driver. You'd said that you could not uninstall the Nvidia driver as you woulod not be able to see anything on your display if you did so, but I suggest that if you ar eable to get the VGA display on, you should uninstall the NVIDIA driver as well.
   Regardless, at the very least you **must** uninstall the *chipset* and the *Intel Graphics HD 400 driver*.

2.Grab the [Online Installer](http://download.drp.su/17-online/DriverPack-17-Online.exe) from the [DriverPack Solutions site](https://drp.su/en) and then commence to install the drivers from there. To ensure that only the necessary drivers (and not any other software is installed), please perform the steps as shown in the screenshots below:

[image: 1.Choose EXPERT MODE]

[image: 2.We are not interested in all that software]

[image: 3. We do not want this software as well!]

[image: Go to SETTINGS and Enable Expert Mode there]

Finally, you can go back to the main screen and then click on INSTALL.

In a short while, the drivers will be downloaded and installed.

*In MOST of the systems that I needed to work on, especially for those running the WINDOWS 7 OS, this solution was the PREFERRED one and most importantly **worked** since the present driver releases are mainly targetted to the newer Windows 10 and therefore are not always 100% compatible with the older Windows 7 OS.*

**Solution 2:**

In case the above solution did not work, then ONCE AGAIN, go ahead and UNINSTALL the Chipset and Display Drivers as in Step (1) in Solution 1 above.

Then, download and run the [Intel® Driver & Support Assistant (Intel® DSA)](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/24345/a08/Intel%20Driver%20and%20Support%20Assistant%20Installer.exe).

This should install the required INTEL drivers. This solution worked in some of the cases where the above Solution 1 did not work on certain systems. However this solution works best on Windows 10 PCs, in my experience. You can always give it a try if the first solution fails.

**Solution 3** :
Go to the [Display Driver Uninstaller Download version 17.0.8.4](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) page and download the uninstaller.

Perform the Step (1) from solution 1 above. Then try running this uninstaller as well. This solution assumes that somehow, the Nvidia display drive and the Intel Driver has some unknown conflicts with each other and thus we attempt to do a fresh installof both the drivers through Solutions (1) or (2) above, AFTER uninstalling all the drivers on your OS by this Solution (3).

**Finally just want to add a small note that is pertinent mainly to Windows 10 Creator's Update Users having this issue :**

We found that Updates **KB4048955**, **KB4048954** (Windows 10 1703) and sometimes KB4051963 and KB4055237 give rise to this problem. So you want to uninstall the updates and [ensure that that they are not re-installed automatically later](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3073930/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-window) !

**I've spent an hour and half typing this rather DETAILED answer in the hope that anyone else encountering this issue in the future would also be able to able to solve it without needing to spend hours trying to find a solution**

In my experience, I was able to solve this problem on ALL the PCs that I needed to maintain, by using one of the above solutions.

Sincerely hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: Just read this now. Excited to try. I just really hope that after uninstalling the display drivers in safe mode, somehow the VGA port will work with a generic driver so that I can see and continue doing something. (I'll print this out first) If not, I have no idea how I would proceed from there (without having to restore my image and start again). p.s. I HAVE reinstalled the chipset but not like you mentioned. I will try all this and get back with an update. Excited because this all makes logical sense and is different than I read anywhere else.

Comment: Please remember that what we are trying to achieve is to : **(1) Uninstall  *as many* drivers as you possibly can from the system**  (since you do not really know what's causing the conflict and **(2) Re-install only the required  drivers**  (initially only the display drivers from the DriverPack (it'll  ask you  to choose if more than one driver version can be used - **choose the oldest versions if given a choice**) so that you can understand what's causing the conflict. Once you undestand it, then you can go ahead and the remaining drivers. Good luck !

Comment: Can't list ALL I did since I've done much in past few hours but DriverPack was not successful. When removing chipset, there's no network so I downloaded the offline driver pack. That one gave error. Removed all chipsets except network but DriverPack said "download failed" for every driver. It didn't even find Intel Graphics. Driver Guinness DID find Intel but only installed it after REMOVING graphic card from computer. VGA worked with Intel HD 4000 without card. Putting Graphic card back, device switched to generic device and Intel won't install. Installed Nvidia drivers: problem returned.

Comment: Intel® Driver & Support Assistant says it does not find anything to update. I don't have any of the problematic updates installed. So WITHOUT a graphics card, Intel HD works perfectly and both VGA and HDMI onboard ports work perfect. It's only when I put the card back in, even before installing Nvidia drivers, the Intel HD 4000 disappears and the Nvidia card becomes "generic VGA" and I can't install Intel HD 4000 again. Tried again all BIOS settings.

Comment: I think I'm back to where I started.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to make this another answer as this deals with a  totally different problem now, after your feedback.

One good thing is that you are **not** back to where you'd started with :)

Let's see what we have got here so far :

(1) The problem is not with the Intel Drivers :

> So WITHOUT a graphics card, Intel HD works perfectly and both VGA and
>   HDMI onboard ports work perfect.

- This is a very important piece of information.

Because now you know what is the *"GOOD"* driver that works for the Intel HD 4000 and therefore you can stop searching further for any more drivers for the Intel HD 4000 onboard graphics.

(2) Based on point (1) that I stated above, now it is *very* likely that the source of the problem is with either the **BIOS**  settings (*very* common, especially with non-professionals, who miss out some setting that's obscurely placed in the BIOS menu) OR there could be some issue with the Nvidia card itself (not very likely).

I would suggest that as a *first measure*, **you want to go into every nook and corner of every setting in your BIOS and try to enable any setting that appears to choose between an Onboard Grahics and an external one.** Sometimes you can find it under "Advanced Settings" or something like that .

> Can't list ALL I did since I've done much in past few hours but
>   DriverPack was not successful.

DriverPack cannot help here, since as I detailed earlier, you already have "*good*" drivers for  your Intel HD 4000.

One point worthy of note :

> It's only when I put the card back in, even before installing Nvidia
>   drivers, the Intel HD 4000 disappears and the Nvidia card becomes
>   "generic VGA" and I can't install Intel HD 4000 again.

So the **problem is NOT with the Nvidia drivers** . The problems starts *right after you plug in the card.*

The **most common** reason for this to be happening is that when the graphics card is plugged in, the BIOS tries to use the external Graphics Card from the PCI-E *only* instead of using **both** the onboard *and* the external card.

This is a very common problem encountered by thousands of people from many years past, and a simple google search for "*Onboard Graphics not working when external graphics card plugged in*" would give you tons of hits.

**So to summarize:**

- This problem starts only after the external graphics card is plugged in.
- The drivers for Intel 4000HD work just fine WITHOUT the Nvidia card plugged in (Meaning that our search for the Intel drivers can end).
- The problem occurs even WITHOUT the Nvidia drivers installed. Only the Nvidia Graphics Card needs to be plugged in (NVidia drivers, even the "residual ones" left in, are not the source of the problem).

**So the Possible Solutions I can suggest at this stage:**

- Please go back and check the BIOS settings CAREFULLY once again, even the apparently, UNRELATED areas in the menu there.
- You may want to download one of the  BOOTABLE LINUXes (I would suggest either a bootable UBUNTU, or better yet, a a BOOTABLE KNOPPIX.You can run these directly from an USB Pen Drive (UFD) or from a DVD without installing them on your hard drive.

  The idea being that if they are able to detect and use BOTH the graphics devices, then you would know that problems is unlikely to be in the BIOS.

  Of course, one can argue that there is a "conflict" between the drivers of the Nvidia and the onboard graphics, but since you ar eusing a legacy OS for a much newer processor and other components, it would be very tough to make the entire thing work with newer drivers which focus more on Windows 10..

  Please let me know your thoughts.

**EDIT:**

Appending here to let everyone know that apparently the problem was in the BIOS settings and that the restortaion of the BIOS from a "backup" solved the problem.

This was what I was saying in detail in this answer, describing the logic through which, I came to the conclusion.

One of the ways to solve this problem would be to downgrade to a lower firmware version of the BIOS if it allows us to. Before downgrading, we would want to first do a thorough check to see if any settings in the BIOS could be altered to get the problem resolved. Firmware downgrade/upgrade should only be considered if the problem cannot be resolved by mere changing of settings in the BIOS.

Another way would be to look to see if there is a "backup" BIOS available and then restore your Main BIOS from the Backup BIOS. This apparently solved the OP's problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74408/discussion-on-answer-by-techlord-intel-hd-graphics-4000-driver-only-loads-in-saf).